# strcat crashes program (0xc0000005)

Tags: c, string, pointers, for-loop, strcat

I need to draw a line of characters as long I want. So I wrote a function for that purpose:

```
void fDrawLine(int length)
{
    int i;
    char * compLine = (char *) malloc(WINDOW_WIDTH + 2);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        strcat(compLine, "-");

    fDrawSpacedMessage(compLine, -1, TRUE);
}
```

`WINDOW_WIDTH` defined as `80`, `fDrawSpacedMessage` is another function to print texts centered etc.

It's building perfectly, no errors, no warnings. But in runtime, everything works but if `fDrawLine` executes, the program crashes and gives the error code `0xc0000005`. I know it's about memory allocation but I already initialize the `compLine` string.

I've tried a couple of things; I thought another function caused it so I isolated `fDrawLine`, but crashing continued. Changing initialize with `compLine[0] = 0;`, `compLine[WINDOW_WIDTH] = {0};` did not help.

It works well with my other machine, which runs Ubuntu, with latest gcc, but when using Code::Blocks (MinGW) on Windows it keeps crashing.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Why you are not using `memset` to fill with '-'? Also what is value of `length`?

Comment: As this is a school project, you're presumably learning to code. Other things aside, look at your function then answer this question: What would the call `fDrawLine(WINDOW_WIDTH*2);` actually do? Learn to program defensively

Comment: 1) Need to insure `length` is not too great.  Add `assert(length < (WINDOW_WIDTH + 1));`  2) `2` is a magic number here.  Provide detail about 2?  (Could `fDrawSpacedMessage()` be failing trying to display an 81 long "---...---"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare `compLine` as a pointer, since you don't need that, and actually you have a memory leak in your function, first declare `compLine` this way

```
char compLine[1 + WINDOW_WIDTH] = {0}; // strings need an extra byte at the end to mark the end.
```

then use `memset` to set the `'-'` character like this

```
memset(compLine, '-', length);
```

of course, check that `length <= WINDOW_WIDTH`.

This is your function fixed, so you can try it

```
void fDrawLine(int length)
{
    char compLine[1 + WINDOW_WIDTH] = {0}; // initialized so that last byte is '\0'.
    if (length > WINDOW_WIDTH)
        length = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    memset(compLine, '-', length);        
    fDrawSpacedMessage(compLine, -1, TRUE);
}
```

besides using `strcat` that way is a bad idea, you can do it this

```
char *compLine = malloc(1 + length); // the last extra '\0' byte.
if (compLine == NULL) // malloc returns NULL on failure to allocate memory
    return; // so we must abort this function in that case.
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    compLine[i] = '-';
compLine[length] = '\0';

fDrawSpacedMessage(compLine, -1, TRUE);
free(compLine);
```

you can also use `memset` in this case, and it is actually better.

Comment: It does not make a big performance difference here, but it's better to manually set `compLine[length]` to `\0` in first example, instead of initializing the whole array as `0`s.

Comment: perhaps, but it is a good habit for new programmers to initialize like this, since they often forget about the terminating `'\0'`, it is by far the most common mistake I have seen. I might of course, be wrong. Some might even get used to `calloc` to avoid this problem.

Comment: If they forget about the terminating '\0' they will forget about initializing the whole array. It's amazing how many developers waste cycles on initializing large buffers before loading them up in the very next line.

Answer (score 1):

The allocated memory starts containing garbage. Set it to an empty string, for example like this:

```
compLine[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: He said this did not help.

Comment: There may very well be other errors. Since we haven't seen a complete but minimal example that still shows the problem, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code below

```
void fDrawLine(int length)
{
    int i;
    char * compLine = (char *) malloc(WINDOW_WIDTH + 2);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        strcat(compLine, "-");

    fDrawSpacedMessage(compLine, -1, TRUE);
}
```

First, the `length` parameter should at least be `unsigned int` as a negative length makes no sense. Ideally, you should use `size_t`. The same goes for `i`.

Next, you are not protecting yourself against invalid values for `length`. The implicit contract is that 0 <= `length` <= `WINDOW_WIDTH` - make it explicit.

Your use of dynamically allocated memory leads to a memory leak as you don't release it after calling `fDrawSpacedMessage()`.

Finally, `strcat` is overkill to append a single character.

Putting all that together, here's an alternative implementation.

```
void fDrawLine(size_t length)
{
    size_t actual_length = length <= WINDOW_WIDTH ? length : WINDOW_WIDTH;
    char compLine[WINDOW_WIDTH+2];

    memset(compLine, '-', actual_length);
    compline[actual_length] = '\0';
    fDrawSpacedMessage(compLine, -1, TRUE);
}
```

I've left `compline` at `WINDOW_WIDTH+2` as I'm guessing `fDrawSpacedMessage` adds a newline.

If it still crashes, the problem is in `fDrawSpacedMessage`